# CVE-2015-0235 How to update eglibc to 2.15-0ubuntu10.10

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, security, glibc

I followed [these instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120381/60758) and found that my glibc version was 2.15-0ubuntu10.9. How do I update it to 2.15-0ubuntu10.10?

It is also mentioned [here](http://ma.ttias.be/critical-glibc-update-cve-2015-0235-gethostbyname-calls/) that services have to be restarted after the update. How do I know which services I have to restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on 12.04 or 10.04, you don't need to do anything special to upgrade. The usual procedure applies:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or, specifically:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

To verify, run `apt-cache policy`:

```
$ apt-cache policy libc6
libc6:
  Installed: 2.15-0ubuntu10.10
  Candidate: 2.15-0ubuntu10.10
  Version table:
 *** 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.15-0ubuntu10.9 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
```

The [USN notice](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2485-1/) is more cautious, and given the core nature of `libc`, I second it:

> After a standard system update you need to reboot your computer to make
>   all the necessary changes.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the reboot. But thank you.

Comment: @topher `libc` is second only to the kernel, IMHO, in importance. With both, the only real option is restarting, since you never know what's hanging around using the old version.

Comment: I'm getting `Installed: 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.20` even after running update and upgrade—and I am running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. Any advice?

Comment: @RubenVerborgh that is the correct version for 10.04. The example output shown above is for 12.04, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks! Seemed weird to me that the version numbers didn't match.