# What is the 'libc gethostbyname buffer overflow' and how can I protect myself from it

Tags: security

Apparently there is a bug in the [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), that can cause a buffer overflow, how can I protect myself from it?!

Reference:

- [oss-security - Qualys Security Advisory CVE-2015-0235 - GHOST: glibc gethostbyname
  buffer overflow](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/01/27/9)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CVE-2015-0235 How to update eglibc to 2.15-0ubuntu10.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/578452/cve-2015-0235-how-to-update-eglibc-to-2-15-0ubuntu10-10)

Comment: Not a dupe. I am asking `What is ...` and `...how can i protect...` he's is `...how to update...`. Therefore IMO, not a dupe.

Comment: OK. I posted an answer since you hadn't yet. Comment when you do, so I can remove it once your more-thorough post comes up.

Comment: @muru, not this time. Last week and a half of Internship, don't have time for that right now. But, your answer seems to be good enough! I'll wait to see what the community thinks, and then I will accept it. Remind me if I forget! :)

Comment: FWIW there's *very* limited value in having more than one question about a single vulnerability. A good question and answer should cover **all** of those (what, why, how to fix, etc) automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Ubuntu Security Notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2485-1/), this affects 10.04 and 12.04 among the currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

## How can I protect myself?

### Upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or, specifically:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

Check the currently installed version using `apt-cache policy libc6`:

- For 12.04, it should be `2.15-0ubuntu10.10`, or higher.
- For 10.04, it should be `2.11.1-0ubuntu7.20`, or higher.

### Restart.

#### `libc` is a core package. You should restart to be sure nothing on your system is using the old version.

At the least, restart ***every*** service running on your system.

## What is it?

The team who discovered this vulnerability has published [an advisory](https://www.qualys.com/research/security-advisories/GHOST-CVE-2015-0235.txt) (posted in the mailing list referred), examining the code involved and case studies. It includes a C program to detect if the system is vulnerable.

Essentially, look-ups of IPv4-style addresses (those involving numbers and dots) can cause this trigger.

> [The] hostname must
>   have one of the following forms: "a.b.c.d", "a.b.c", "a.b", or "a",
>   where a, b, c, d must be unsigned integers, at most 0xfffffffful,
>   converted successfully (ie, no integer overflow) by strtoul() in
>   decimal or octal (but not hexadecimal, because 'x' and 'X' are
>   forbidden).

This is due to a miscalculation in the size of a buffer needed, where the size is a bit short, allowing a `strcpy` down the line to write past the end of the buffer by a limited amount (4 bytes on 32-bit machines, or 8 bytes on 64-bit machines).

An exploit has been written by the team against the Exim mail server, but the code has not been released yet.

The list of services affected [include, but is not limited to](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/01/highly-critical-ghost-allowing-code-execution-affects-most-linux-systems/):

> MySQL servers, Secure Shell servers, form submission apps, and other types of mail servers. ... Apache, Cups, Dovecot, GnuPG, isc-dhcp, lighttpd, mariadb/mysql, nfs-utils, nginx, nodejs, openldap, openssh, postfix, proftpd, pure-ftpd, rsyslog, samba, sendmail, sysklogd, syslog-ng, tcp_wrappers, vsftpd, and xinetd.

---

Apparently the test code is [available on the University of Chicago website](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80210/ghost-bug-is-there-a-simple-way-to-test-if-my-system-is-secure). Therefore you can do:

```
wget https://webshare.uchicago.edu/orgs/ITServices/itsec/Downloads/GHOST.c
gcc GHOST.c -o GHOST
./GHOST
```

The final output would be `vulnerable` or `not vulnerable`.